Login and mongo db error when logging using spring security
I am trying to have a local project up and running using mongodb, springboot, spring-security and docker as tech stack. I am facing a couple issues when running the application:

Any url is getting redirected to /login, even though I have configured few urls to bypass authentication.
I am getting this error during start-up (not sure if this is breaking) :com.mongodb.MongoNodeIsRecoveringException: Command failed with error 11600 (InterruptedAtShutdown): 'interrupted at shutdown' on server mongo:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "interrupted at shutdown", "code": 11600, "codeName": "InterruptedAtShutdown"}
Also, when I put any username and password to /login page , it sends me this error:

Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='encora', source='taskmanagement', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
Below are the concerned classes:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
  @Bean
  protected SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .cors()
        .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers((request) -> request.getServletPath().startsWith("/api/auth"))
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin();

    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

I have also tried to use .antMatchers("/api/auth") instead of .requestMatchers and still getting an error.
Below is the controller class:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class UserController {

  @Autowired private UserService userService;

  @PostMapping("/createUser")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  public void createUser(@NotNull @RequestBody User user) {
    LOGGER.info("Creating user: {}", user.getUsername());
    userService.saveUser(user);
  }

Below is the service class:
@Service
public class UserService {

  @Autowired private UserRepository userRepository;

  public User saveUser(User user) {
    user.setPassword(
        hashPassword(user.getPassword()));

    return userRepository.save(user);
  }

Below are the concerned dependencies:
<groupId>org.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>team-management</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>team-management</name>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.18</version>
        </dependency>

Below are the docker files:
version: '3.1'

services:
  team-management:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: team-management
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    entrypoint: "java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar"

  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db
      - ./init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: taskmanagement
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: encora
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: training
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
volumes:
  mongodb_data:

Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:8

ARG JAR_FILE=target/team-management.jar

COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-classpath", "app.jar", "org.encora.myapp.TeamManagementApplication"]
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]

